# Flatten nested Pydantic model

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

```py
from typing import Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Category(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(alias="name")


class OrderItems(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(alias="name")
    category: Category = Field(alias="category")
    unit: Union[str, None] = Field(alias="unit")
    quantity: int = Field(alias="quantity")
```

When instantiated like this:

```py
OrderItems(**{'name': 'Test','category':{'name': 'Test Cat'}, 'unit': 'kg', 'quantity': 10})
```

It returns data like this:

```py
OrderItems(name='Test', category=Category(name='Test Cat'), unit='kg', quantity=10)
```

But I want the output like this:

```py
OrderItems(name='Test', category='Test Cat', unit='kg', quantity=10)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How are you returning data and getting JSON?

Comment: ```cursor = order_collection.find()
return [OrderItems(**item) async for item in cursor]```

Comment: What do you need the `Category` model for then? Why not just define `category: str` and initialize it with the value `"Test Cat"` right away?

Comment: I need to insert category data like model

Comment: Then you should probably have a different model for _inserting_ than the one you use for _responding_. That is the usual FastAPI practice anyway. In the _response_ model you could define `category: str` and use a a regular validator with `pre=True` to handle the dictionary.

Comment: Category table has more data, I only show here name. Like slug, image and other stuffs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try as much as possible to define your schema the way you *actually* want the data to look in the end, not the way you might *receive* it from somewhere else.

---

### UPDATE: Generalized solution (one nested field or more)

To generalize this problem, let's assume you have the following models:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Foo(BaseModel):
    x: bool
    y: str
    z: int


class _BarBase(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: float

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class BarNested(_BarBase):
    foo: Foo


class BarFlat(_BarBase):
    foo_x: bool
    foo_y: str
```

**Problem**: You want to be able to initialize `BarFlat` with a `foo` argument just like `BarNested`, but the data to end up in the flat schema, wherein the fields `foo_x` and `foo_y` correspond to `x` and `y` on the `Foo` model (and you are not interested in `z`).

**Solution**: Define a custom [`root_validator`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#root-validators) with `pre=True` that checks if a `foo` key/attribute is present in the data. If it is, it validates the corresponding object against the `Foo` model, grabs its `x` and `y` values and then uses them to extend the given data with `foo_x` and `foo_y` keys:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator
from pydantic.utils import GetterDict

...

class BarFlat(_BarBase):
    foo_x: bool
    foo_y: str

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def flatten_foo(cls, values: GetterDict) -> GetterDict | dict[str, object]:
        foo = values.get("foo")
        if foo is None:
            return values
        # Assume `foo` must ba valid `Foo` data:
        foo = Foo.validate(foo)
        return {
            "foo_x": foo.x,
            "foo_y": foo.y,
        } | dict(values)
```

Note that we need to be a bit more careful inside a root validator with `pre=True` because the values are always passed in the form of a [`GetterDict`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#data-binding), which is an immutable mapping-like object. So we cannot simply assign new values `foo_x`/`foo_y` to it like we would to a dictionary. But nothing is stopping us from *returning* the cleaned up data in the form of a regular old `dict`.

To demonstrate, we can throw some test data at it:

```py
test_dict = {"a": "spam", "b": 3.14, "foo": {"x": True, "y": ".", "z": 0}}
test_orm = BarNested(a="eggs", b=-1, foo=Foo(x=False, y="..", z=1))
test_flat = '{"a": "beans", "b": 0, "foo_x": true, "foo_y": ""}'
bar1 = BarFlat.parse_obj(test_dict)
bar2 = BarFlat.from_orm(test_orm)
bar3 = BarFlat.parse_raw(test_flat)
print(bar1.json(indent=4))
print(bar2.json(indent=4))
print(bar3.json(indent=4))
```

The output:

```json
{
    "a": "spam",
    "b": 3.14,
    "foo_x": true,
    "foo_y": "."
}
```

```json
{
    "a": "eggs",
    "b": -1.0,
    "foo_x": false,
    "foo_y": ".."
}
```

```json
{
    "a": "beans",
    "b": 0.0,
    "foo_x": true,
    "foo_y": ""
}
```

The first example simulates a common situation, where the data is passed to us in the form of a nested dictionary. The second example is the typical database ORM object situation, where `BarNested` represents the schema we find in a database. The third is just to show that we can still correctly initialize `BarFlat` *without* a `foo` argument.

One caveat to note is that the validator does *not* get rid of the `foo` key, if it finds it in the `values`. If your model is configured with [`Extra.forbid`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/model_config/#options) that will lead to an error. In that case, you'll just need to have an extra line, where you coerce the original `GetterDict` to a `dict` first, then [`pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) the `"foo"` key instead of [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)ting it.

---

### Original post (flatten single field)

If you need the nested `Category` model for database insertion, but you want a "flat" order model with `category` being just a string in the response, you should split that up into two separate models.

Then in the response model you can define a custom validator with [`pre=True`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) to handle the case when you attempt to initialize it providing an instance of `Category` or a `dict` for `category`.

Here is what I suggest:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Category(BaseModel):
    name: str


class OrderItemBase(BaseModel):
    name: str
    unit: str | None
    quantity: int


class OrderItemCreate(OrderItemBase):
    category: Category


class OrderItemResponse(OrderItemBase):
    category: str

    @validator("category", pre=True)
    def handle_category_model(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, Category):
            return v.name
        if isinstance(v, dict) and "name" in v:
            return v["name"]
        return v
```

Here is a demo:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    insert_data = '{"name": "foo", "category": {"name": "bar"}, "quantity": 1}'
    insert_obj = OrderItemCreate.parse_raw(insert_data)
    print(insert_obj.json(indent=2))
    ...  # insert into DB
    response_obj = OrderItemResponse.parse_obj(insert_obj.dict())
    print(response_obj.json(indent=2))
```

Here is the output:

```json
{
  "name": "foo",
  "unit": null,
  "quantity": 1,
  "category": {
    "name": "bar"
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "name": "foo",
  "unit": null,
  "quantity": 1,
  "category": "bar"
}
```

One of the benefits of this approach is that the JSON Schema stays consistent with what you have on the model. If you use this in `FastAPI` that means the swagger documentation will actually reflect what the consumer of that endpoint receives. You could of course override and customize schema creation, but... why? Just define the model correctly in the first place and avoid headache in the future.

Comment: much more sane than my answer

Comment: @daniil-fajnberg without pre it also works fine. I think I need without pre. Request need to validate as pydantic model

Comment: @Daniil Fjanberg, very nice! However, how could this work if you would like to flatten two additional attributes from the `Category` class, (e.g. `attr1` and `attr2`). How would the response model look like and do we need separate validators for each attribute (so one for `category (name)`, `attr1` and `attr2`?

Comment: @MrNetherlands As I said, _you_ should define how you want your response model to look. Once you do that, the rest becomes just a matter of _"how can we make our data look like this?"_ If you had `Category` with `attr1` and `attr2` and wanted to have a response with fields like `category_attr1` and `category_attr2` for example, you could define a [`root_validator`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#root-validators) to grab the `category` object and assign its attribute values accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, `root_validator` seems indeed the way to go. However, within the validation function the `values` argument is of class `GetterDict` which does not allow value assigment `values["attr1"] = values["category"].attr1` yields: `'GetterDict' object does not support item assignment (type=type_error)`

Comment: @MrNetherlands Yes, you are right, that needs to be handled a bit differently than with a regular `dict`. This is not documented ([because Pydantic v2 comes soon](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/4698) anyway). I updated my answer to present a more generalized solution first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this when instantiating:

```
myCategory = Category(name="test cat")
OrderItems(
    name="test",
    category=myCategory.name,
    unit="kg",
    quantity=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, i was curious, so here's the insane way:

```
class Category(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(alias="name")


class OrderItems(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(alias="name")
    category: Category = Field(alias="category")
    unit: Union[str, None] = Field(alias="unit")
    quantity: int = Field(alias="quantity")
    
    def json(self, *args, **kwargs) -> str:
        self.__dict__.update({'category': self.__dict__['category'].name})
        return super().json(*args, **kwargs)
    
c = Category(name='Dranks')
m = OrderItems(name='sodie', category=c, unit='can', quantity=1)
m.json()
```

And you get:

```
'{"name": "sodie", "category": "Dranks", "unit": "can", "quantity": 1}'
```

The sane way would probably be:

```
class Category(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(alias="name")


class OrderItems(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(alias="name")
    category: Category = Field(alias="category")
    unit: Union[str, None] = Field(alias="unit")
    quantity: int = Field(alias="quantity")
    
c = Category(name='Dranks')
m = OrderItems(name='sodie', category=c, unit='can', quantity=1)

r = m.dict()
r['category'] = r['category']['name']
```

Comment: Your first way is nice. I already using this way. I was finding any better way like built in method to achieve this type of output. I also tried for root_validator

Comment: The only other 'option' i saw was maybe using https://github.com/Maydmor/pydantic-computed that is just the name, and exclude=True the actual category field.

Comment: The first is a very bad idea for a multitude of reasons. You are circumventing a lot of inner machinery that makes Pydantic models useful by going directly via `__dict__`, you are destroying the purpose of the type annotation, you are setting data that will not conform to the JSON schema returned by the model, .... The second is viable of course, but I wonder why you would not just override the `dict` method to do that and then override `json` to call `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a variant which supports `pydantic>=2.0`. I use the solution by @Daniil Fajnberg.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator
from pydantic.v1.utils import GetterDict

class Foo(BaseModel):
    x: bool
    y: str
    z: int

class _BarBase(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: float

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True

class BarNested(_BarBase):
    foo: Foo

class BarFlat(_BarBase):
    foo_x: bool
    foo_y: str

    @model_validator(mode="before")
    def flatten_foo(cls, values: GetterDict):
        foo = values.get("foo")
        if foo is None:
            return values
        foo = Foo.model_validate(foo)

        result = {
            "foo_x": foo.x,
            "foo_y": foo.y,
        }
        result.update(values)
        return result

data = {"a": "spam", "b": 3.14, "foo": {"x": True, "y": ".", "z": 0}}

print(BarFlat(**data))
```