# How to return nested list from html forms usingf pydantic?

Tags: list, forms, fastapi, pydantic

Trying to return form data in a nested list. Current code returns the below format:

```
{
   "name":"meal number 4",
   "description":"new description",
   "ing_qty":"4",
   "ing_type":"small",
   "ing_name":"Tomato",
   "ing_id":"9"
}
```

Printing raw FormData results in:

> FormData([('name', 'meal number 4'), ('description', 'new
> description'), ('ing_qty', '4'), ('ing_type', 'small'), ('ing_name',
> 'Onion'), ('ing_id', '6'), ('ing_qty', '4'), ('ing_type', 'small'),
> ('ing_name' , 'Red'), ('ing_id', '7'), ('ing_qty', '4'), ('ing_type',
> 'small'), ('ing_name', 'Tomato'), ('ing_id', '8'), ('ing_qty', '4'),
> ('ing_type', 'small'), ('ing_name', 'Tomato'), ('ing_id', '9')])

I am trying to get the results into the below format so that i may update my db recrds with the form data.

```
{
   "name":"string",
   "description":"string",
   "ingredients":[
      {
         "ing_id":null,
         "ing_qty":null,
         "ing_type":null,
         "ing_name":null
      }
   ]
}
```

Here are my Pydantic BaseModels

```
class IngUpdate(BaseModel):
    ing_id: Optional[int]
    ing_qty: Optional[int]
    ing_type: Optional[str]
    ing_name: Optional[str]


class RecipeUpdate(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str]
    description: Optional[str]
    ingredients: List[IngUpdate] = []
```

Here is my Post Request:

```
@router.post("/edit/{recipe_id}")
async def edit_select_recipe(request: Request, recipe_id: int,
                             db: Session = Depends(get_db)):

    data = await request.form()

    print(data)
    return data
```

Adding Response Model to Post returns the following result:

```
{
   "name":"meal number 4",
   "description":"new description",
   "ingredients":[
      
   ]
}
```

It appears it's unable to pull the data into a list. How can I get this into a nest model?

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to read (please fomat the JSON to be readable and clarify what it is you want) but it seems like you're not using you're Pydantic models?

Comment: Plain form data doesn't have a nested structure - if you want to get a nested structure directly from a POST, use a JSON body instead of plain form data - or create a flat structure that you transform into the one you want (with `ing_id: Optional[List[int]] = Form()`, `ing_qty: Optional[List[str]] = Form()`, etc., then convert this to the format you want to submit to your db/service layer.

Comment: Related (opposite problem): https://stackoverflow.com/q/75289130/19770795